# Why is Ping Federate memberOf attribute causing ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, ping

Due to company policy, I am very limited in what I am able to share.... so please try not to be too tough on me.

I have a .net 6 mvc web application that I have integrated with PingOne.

Authentication is working for users within my organization. I have added the memberOf attribute in order to obtain user groups and additional information.

After that change is in place, I try to login again and I am greeted with the following screen.
[image]

- I have checked IISExpress logs and nothing there indicates a problem.
- Verified that my response is reaching ping and they are sending response back.
- Response size of the cookies when adding the memberOf attribute is very large.... ~24,000. Previously it was under 4,000.
  [image: List item]

I want to know if anyone has any possible solutions to this problem. If it were an http header limit issue,  I would expect to see that error but the cookie size is the only significant difference I can gather after the memberOf attribute is added. The site can be reached, just not after it reaches ping and redirects back to my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out more detailed error information by downloading a free version of the Fiddler tool from telerik.

This indeed did confirm suspicions that the header limit was being reached. After reducing the size of the response the application site is now reachable.